# Using SAP BODS to load data to Snowflake it is taking a lot of time

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, sap-data-services

Using SAP BODS to load data to Snowflake it is taking a lot of time.

BODS job is simple source (HANA table) query then Target as Snowflake table.

Just to load 6 records with 10 columns it is taking more than half an hour.

I analyzed where most of the time is going in checking metadata data. I tried updating the ODBC driver to 2.24.0 still loading time is high.

Observe select/insert takes very less but searching metadata is very time consuming:

[image: Observe select/insert takes very less but searching metadata is very time consuming]

Comment: Please fix your use of ALL CAPS, people think you are SHOUTING at them.

Comment: Those Snowflake statements are taking a few seconds/milliseconds. Whatever is taking half an hour is not in Snowflake (or at least not in the statements you are showing)

Comment: ​  Finally able to reduce time by very minimum by setting 

CLIENT_METADATA_REQUEST_USE_CONNECTION_CTX='TRUE' 


But still, all the target table columns are checked in db.schema, which is unnecessary now trying to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable [ODBC logging](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#ODBC) to check if there is any specific Driver call that is taking the extra amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

​Finally able to reduce time by very minimum by setting

CLIENT_METADATA_REQUEST_USE_CONNECTION_CTX='TRUE'

But still, all the target table columns are checked in db.schema, which is unnecessary now trying to find the answer.